# Entity Framework Function Import returns incorrect Column Information

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to import a function `spa_SessionLoad` which should be returning a particular row from my `Session` management table.  When I click on the 'Get Column Information' button, it instead pulls the info from a different stored procedure (`spa_InventoryUpdate`), which returns a single string.

I'm working with a sql 2008 database, using database-first methods.

I've built a few other function imports, and they all seem to be correct.
I've verified the code on the SQL Server returns a row when the sproc is executed.

The culprit seems to be that my 'Load' function contains some cleanup code to deal with abandoned sessions, which ultimately calls the `spa_InventoryUpdate` procedure.  The import tool seems to be getting confused with the return of that `EXEC` call, instead of the one for the 'Load' .

At any rate, how can I get the function imported, if its pulling the wrong return info?

Thanks

Comment: there is no code.  I click a button on the VS interface, and it returns the 'wrong' data.

Comment: show the code for your `spa_SessionLoad` ... I've ran into this problem before, and each time it was something different to fix it

Comment: _how can I get the function imported_ - You can always resort to editing the edmx manually, following examples of other function imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if you know the actual return type you can just specify it in the UI.  In my case, I knew it was really returning a single "session" row, so I selected my "session" EF object, and everything worked as required.